# Do any phones support a "night mode" (inside vs. outside) for ambient light detection

Tags: detection, light, ambient

Optimal screen colors differ in outside sunlight, at night, and inside lighting. Is there any way to detect the ambient light conditions in any Android phone or other mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

It's sadly not possible in iOS at least. (Accessing details of the ambient light sensor are off-limits (as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691821/ambient-light-sensors-in-iphone))

[An interesting hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753165/detecting-if-iphone-is-in-a-dark-room/22836060#22836060) is to access the front-facing camera and analyze the brightness of a captured image.