# Ambient light sensors in iphone

Tags: ios, ambient

In our app, If a user covers the top area of iphone where ambient light sensors are available, i want to get the changing value of ambient light sensors. I don't want to manipulate those value as i understand Apple doesn't allow to play with hardware . 
My objective is to get that value of ambient light sensors. This is testing application which is checking if ambient light sensors are working correctly or not.

I spent lot of time, but couldn't find any thing yet. I tried with UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification, but this is for screen brightness.

Similar kind of functionality is available in android and i could get the value of Ambient light sensors.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but take a look at this page: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AppleISL29003

Comment: This link is using Private API and apple will not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the light sensors are off limits.

Comment: Apple allows only a simple YES or NO for the proximity sensor detection.

Comment: Yes, This is only for proximity sensors. I am looking for any kind of information from Ambient light sensors.

Comment: [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/proximityState) for @ecsos's comment